# How to optimize multi select comparing/join with only one table SQL

Tags: sql, join

I must join employee 3 times on 3 conditions. Can I join employee once on 3 conditions?

```
select 
referType = resAffType,

referName = (case when resAffType = 0 then e.empFirstName + ' ' + e.empLastName

when resAffType = 1 then affFirstName + ' ' + affLastName

else NULL end),

bookName = e3.empFirstName + ' ' + e3.empLastName,

AssignToName = e2.empFirstName + ' ' + e2.empLastName,

from

Reservation r 

left join ClubTable c on r.TableISN = c.TableISN 

left join Affiliate a on r.AffiliateISN = a.AffiliateISN -- r.aff maybe in table aff

left join Employee e on r.AffiliateISN = e.EmployeeISN -- r.aff maybe in table emp

left join Employee e2 on r.EmployeeISN = e2.EmployeeISN -- assignedby emp

inner join Employee e3 on r.EmployeeISN = e3.EmployeeISN -- bookedby emp
```

Comment: You can join on multiple conditions, as per an answer below, but that is not going to give you the same result set as you would see from your sample query above.  In short, what you are already doing is correct.

Comment: ok, tk for your reply :)

Comment: Can you double-check your code?  It looks like your join condition is identical on your last two joins, only one is a left and one is an inner.  I'm guessing it's a typo.  Out of curiosity, what is the disadvantage of the approach you listed, joining on the same table three times?  It's a perfectly sound methodology.  Just curious to understand the context of your question

Comment: @hambone: it's just an example, some join i need to connect not null so, left or inner, no problems. What i need really is anyway to optimize it ?
you see, employee have 3 time join on employeeISN.
sorry for my bad knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

No.  What you are already doing is correct.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10256175)

Comment: @Chris How does it not answer the question? If the answer is no, there's really nothing else to add.

Comment: @Lundin The question is kinda low quality, so the answer with yes/no must be low quality too. It makes more sense to be a comment, in my opinion.

Comment: @Chris It attempts to answer the question. For posts that are merely bad or technically incorrect, use down votes/comments. Delete votes should only be cast on spam, unsalvageable crap, non-answers and link-only answers etc.